# GoogleBigQuery SQL: Make Rolling Avg Subquery or Join More Efficient For Large Dataset

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, correlated-subquery, rolling-computation

First off, I've figured out how to get what I need using a subquery or join. The problems I've been facing, because of my lack of experience with GBQ:

1. GBQ doesn't allow "correlated subqueries"
2. because the amount of data I'm querying (+500m rows), the join seems to be taking a large amount of time (+3hours), and I'm guessing the query is probably inefficient

Basically for each row, I'm looking calculate the average of some rows, where the rows should meet the condition where (current_row_value-x <= other_row_value < current_row_value-1)

Using https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_join as data, and the following query:

```
SELECT *, (select avg(Quantity) from OrderDetails as table_2 where table_2.OrderId between table_1.OrderId-3 and table_1.OrderId-1) as avg_quant_3 FROM OrderDetails as table_1 order by OrderId asc
```

It outputs the results I need:

```
Number of Records: 518
OrderDetailID   OrderID ProductID   Quantity    avg_quant_3
1   10248   11  12  null
2   10248   42  10  null
3   10248   72  5   null
4   10249   14  9   27
5   10249   51  40  27
6   10250   41  10  76
7   10250   51  35  76
8   10250   65  15  76
9   10251   22  6   136
10  10251   57  15  136
11  10251   65  20  136
12  10252   20  40  150
```

I can't use the above format of the query because GBQ doesn't accept correlated subqueries. So here is the join version, where the results are a bit different (omits rows where the avg can't be calculated), but still correct. I also added all the columns in "group by" because GBQ won't accept a query using an aggregation function without grouping or aggregating all columns being selected:

```
SELECT table_1.OrderDetailID, table_1.OrderID,table_1.ProductID, table_1.Quantity, sum(table_2.quantity) FROM OrderDetails as table_1
join OrderDetails as table_2 on table_2.OrderId between table_1.OrderId-3 and table_1.OrderId-1  
group by table_1.OrderDetailID, table_1.OrderID,table_1.ProductID, table_1.Quantity
```

```
Number of Records: 515
OrderDetailID   OrderID ProductID   Quantity    sum(table_2.quantity)
4   10249   14  9   27
5   10249   51  40  27
6   10250   41  10  76
7   10250   51  35  76
8   10250   65  15  76
9   10251   22  6   136
10  10251   57  15  136
11  10251   65  20  136
12  10252   20  40  150
```

The problem here is that the join is taking +3hours and actually fails due to taking too long. From my experience with GBQ so far, it seems joins take a long amount of time, but then again I am querying a large dataset. I'm wondering if there are any other ways I can obtain this info with a more efficient query, and I can hopefully learn something to become more efficient with GBQ in the future. Also tried running the join version of the query on 5m rows and it's taking +1hour, so I'm also expecting to fail too.

Comment: I just do not get how `AVG()` is going to produce numbers larger than anything in the column.

Answer (score 0):

Could you show the error that you've got trying to run a "correlated subquery"? Below query works for me:

```sql
create temp table table1
as select 1 as x, 2 as y
 union all select 3, 4;

create temp table table2
as select 3 x;

select *, (select avg(y) from table1 where table1.x = table2.x)
from table2
order by x;
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a sum.  And using window functions:

```
select t.*,
       sum(quantity) over (order by orderid
                           range between 3 preceding and 1 preceding
                          ) as TheThingYouCallAnAverage
from t;
```